# How to get the current active text within a scrolled DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

A chipped `DIV` containing paragraphs that need a scrollbar

e.g.

```
<div id="text" style='overflow:scroll;width:200px;height:200px'>

<div style='font-size:64px;'>BIG TEXT</div> 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
industry. Lorem Ipsum    has been the industry's standard dummy text ever  
since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it 
to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also 
the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets 
containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software 
like Aldus PageMaker 
including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

</div>
```

When the scrollbar move, the text change (due to `overflow:scroll`), is it possible to **select only the text displayed in the current view port?**

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cxgkY/15/

**Updated: The inner HTML might contains variable sized text**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a little demo that should do what you're expecting: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/Mmpgc/21/) (works with variable sizes as well). The idea is to automatically create a separate `span` for each word, and then, each time the `div` is scrolled, check which `span`s are visible (by checking their `top` offset), thus updating document selection range. If anything isn't clear I'd be glad to explain it.

Comment: is this intended to select the entire viewport? it just select the first words in my chrome brower...

Comment: @lzprgmr Fixed -- works now, please take a look at the updated demo. Thanks for notifying me!

Comment: cool, works now. btw - this is a brilliant solution, thanks, I learned something.

Comment: Just a follow up, is it possible to handle img tag also? http://jsfiddle.net/Mmpgc/23/ Never mind if you can't, Thanks..

Comment: If you write some code to make sure the img tag belong to one <span>, it should work, I tried by tweaking in chrome developer tools

Comment: Does only mark the very long text, but doesnt show visible part in results.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by selecting just the text in the current viewport, but maybe something like this:

```
var elm = $("#text"),
    t = $(elm).text().split(' '),
    html = [],
    selected_text = '';

$.each(t, function(i,e) {
    html.push('<span>'+e+'</span>');
});

elm.html(html.join(' '));

$('span', elm).each(function(i,e) {
    if ($(e).offset().top < elm.height()) {
        $(e).css('background', 'red');
        selected_text += $(e).text()+' ';
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxgkY/13/)

If the point of this exercise is to just display the text in another container element you can just do it the regular way and fake it:

```
$("#text").on('scroll', function() {
    $('#visible').html($(this).html()).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cxgkY/19/)
    ​

Comment: I think your solution is close, except the use of `text()` method removed the html, maybe it is possible to wrap a span in every existing characters? but preserving the HTML?

Comment: @Howard - What do you intend to use this for, is just to display the text in another element, like Speransky's example, or do you need to select text and change it somehow ??

Comment: @Howard Well, it **is** possible to do that -- partially, anyway. Please refer to the updated demo in my answer.

Comment: adeneo, good point for the "faking" thing. Although there's a bit of "error" because apparently the scrollbars count into height.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this (See DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/cxgkY/14/):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="text">
    <div id="wrapper">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
</div>
```

​
    ​
**JavaScript:**

```
$('#text').scroll(function () {
  var text = $(this).text();

  var begin = $(this).scrollTop() / 
      $(this).children('#wrapper').height();

  var end = begin + $(this).height() /
    $(this).children('#wrapper').height();

  var text = text.slice(text.length * begin, text.length * end);
  $('#visible').text(text);
});
```

Comment: @lzprgmr, thanks for your input, but it didn't work if html contains variable sized text, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/cxgkY/15/

Comment: @SperanskyDanil Yes, sorry for that, I have updated the description.

Comment: @Howard - this seems incredibly awkward, and you should probably reconsider your entire approach as any solution will just be a hack of sorts, and probably not very accurate. I just can't think of any scenario where this would be needed ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="text">
    <p>Line 1</p>
    <p>Line 2</p>
    <p>Line 3</p>

</div>
```

You could do..

```
$(function(){
    var meanLineHeight = $('#text > p').first().outerHeight();

    var result = $('#result');

    $('#text').scroll(function(){
        var linesScrolled = Math.ceil(this.scrollTop/ meanLineHeight);
        console.log(linesScrolled);

        var linesToSelect = $('#text > p').slice(linesScrolled);
        linesToSelect.css('background-color', 'yellow');
    });​​​​​​​
});
```

**[​DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/cxgkY/17/)**

Comment: Thanks, sorry that I have updated the problem, which the text might not be equal height

Comment: @Howard: Can you update my fiddle and try? My guess is the variable height should increase the computed height of the `p` elements.